# Can I view Session State Value at client-side using Chrome DevTools?

Tags: asp.net, session, google-chrome-devtools

I was just curious if we can get/view Session variables values for a website using Chrome DevTools.

If anyone knows, please share.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, you cannot view session state variables at client side. Session state is stored at server, and Client browser only knows SessionID *which is stored in cookie or URL*.

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

> Sessions are identified by a unique identifier that can be read by
>   using the SessionID property. When session state is enabled for an
>   ASP.NET application, each request for a page in the application is
>   examined for a SessionID value sent from the browser. If no SessionID
>   value is supplied, ASP.NET starts a new session and the SessionID
>   value for that session is sent to the browser with the response.
>
> By default, SessionID values are stored in a cookie. However, you can
>   also configure the application to store SessionID values in the URL
>   for a "cookieless" session.

Chrome Browser has few extensions to view cookie. I use `Edit This Cookie`.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Session is maintained at server side. You can view cookies with session ids at client side. so chrome will help you to that only.

if you are using apache server then the file with same name as session can be found on server & all variables can be checked.

Comment: Thanks for Answering Anand, but is it possible through Chrome DevTools ?

Comment: NO it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on ASP.NET you could potentially use Glimpse, a client-side "inspector" that overlays your webpage and shows you what's happening on the server-side. It's great, and the plugins library makes it even nicer to see other things like DB queries the page made and so on.

http://getglimpse.com/