# Get value of session variable with dynamically created session name

Tags: javascript, session

I am trying to see if a session variable exists and what the value is in Javascript.

I tried the following -

```
 var sessionVarName = '<%= Common.PNCSearchedSession %>' + selectedPersonObjectRef;
 var sessionVar = '<%= Session["' + sessionVarName + '"] %>';
```

this just gives me an empty string even though the session variable exists and contains true.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Kev.

Comment: Can't run PHP.  Not allowed I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry ASP - same problem - you are trying to access a server variable using client variables. Can only be done with AJAX

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956860/can-i-view-session-state-value-at-client-side-using-chrome-devtools

Comment: Thanks.  That helps, I know what to do now.  Thanks for your help.